# Database portable Jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I use iReport designed jrxmls for Jasper reports
I have done database specific functions and DML queries like date format, string concatenation, concatenate symbol(||) etc.

My Question is, "Is there any way or plug-in to make the jrxml files to be database portable?".

Thanks in advance,
Kalaiselvan.

Answer (score 0):

You are using JDBC, so your reports are already **kind of** portable unless you use some vendor-specific SQL functions or features.

You could write your OWN datasource in JasperReports (do implement `JRDataSource` interface), and provide your own layer of database independence. It shouldn't be **that** hard.

Answer (score 0):

Each report is filled from a data source like a database, but you knew that. Since the report is filled by fetching data from a specific database with queries to specific rows, if you want to make your .jrxml files database portable (or your .jasper files for that matter) you will need to make your data source and sql queries parameters which are fed into your report file from your program.  It is pretty straight forward to make the data source and SQL query a parameter using iReport.

Comment: Thanks Sean, This is what I am going to do. Thanks to Pablo.